# Why is a newline in a triple-quotation string in F# not the same as Environment.NewLine?

Tags: f#

It appears that newlines in a triple-quote string in F# are translated to LF on Windows (as well as Linux), not CRLF. However, `Environment.NewLine` is CRLF on Windows.

On Windows:

```
let tripleQuotedString = """1
2
3"""
let concatenatedString = "1" + Environment.NewLine + "2" + Environment.NewLine + "3";;
printfn "%A" (Seq.toList tripleQuotedString) // yields ['1'; '\010'; '2'; '\010'; '3']
printfn "%A" (Seq.toList concatenatedString ) // yields ['1'; '\013'; '\010'; '2'; '\013'; '\010'; '3']
```

This doesn't appear to be mentioned in the [F# spec](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/). Is it a deliberate design decision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triple quote string's line ending is same as source code file line ending.